# Change Windows 10 kernel language

Tags: windows, operating-system, kernel, settings, windows-10

I have a computer on Windows 10 system and I would like change the English default language to the French language.

I have already change the language into the setting interface, but I would like get all my computer text in french or an big part.

How I can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should use the language pack and set it as a default - [see for the reference on how to do that](http://www.howtogeek.com/232659/how-to-change-the-display-language-in-windows-10/). If you use Single Language Pack Windows edition, than it could be changed by replacing the default language pack by the different one.